# Alternative to pandas isin() to remove unwanted rows which contain specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a faster or better alternative to pandas isin()? I am trying to filter a large dataset which contains multiple locations and multiple customers. Isin is giving me an error where the array is too large for it to process.

Is there an alternative to what I am doing below? I need to drop rows for a specific location where the customer's status is marked as inactive. I need to use the specific location value and then remove the inactive statuses.

```
inactive = ['Inactive1','Inactive2,'Inactive3', etc.]
df = df.drop(df[(df['location'] == 'ABC123') & (~df.isin(inactive))])
```

Isin() typically does work, HOWEVER, for a dataframe of this size, it is not.

Comment: Looks like you check the entire dataframe for 'isin' can you only filter down to checking a single column?  maybe like `df['status'].isin(inactive)`?

Comment: I should have added this into my original post. When I tried this it returns a KeyError where I get the following error,KeyError: "[all other df columns] not found in axis"

Comment: Okay.... 'all other df columns' that isn't the column name.  Do you have specific columns you are checking for inactive?  Is it one or serveral?

Comment: I'm looking specifically at the location value and the status of the client but want to keep all other columns for each row. I essentially want to keep the original df which contains their contact details and other information, filtering that list to remove any inactive clients at each location. df = df.drop(df[(df['location'] == 'ABC123') & (~df['status'].isin(inactive))]) would work wonderfully if I can get around the keyerror,

Comment: The key error is telling you that you don't have a column named 'status' in this case.   You need the exact column name include whitespaces.    df.columns should show you all your exact column names.   Then `df['status'].isin(inactive)` should work.

Comment: Amateur oversight. I needed to incorporate .index at the end of the boolean logic to provide it the specific rows to drop. Final piece of code looks like df = df.drop(df[(df['location'] == 'ABC123') & (~df.isin(inactive))].index)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you add .index after the boolean logic to make sure the rows are being provided to the .drop() function